# mysql.sock missing after xampp install on windows

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql.sock

I'm guessing that's why I can only connect through phpmyadmin — From that perspective all looks fine. Attempts to connect though php from my code all fail with "(HY000/1045): Access denied for user" (and yes I've checked the usernames and passwords I'm using).

I've tried stopping and restarting MySQL.

A little history: The first stack I installed was bitnami wampstack, but that was a pain so I uninstalled it and installed xampp.

I've searched for clues about how to fix this, but I've come up short.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: In the application logs I've found the following:

Comment: In the application logs I've found the following: "Server socket created on IP: '::'." I presume that that means that the system is trying to create the socket but doesn't have the correct setting for where to create it. That sort of seems to relate to something else that I didn't understand. My three root users are set to "localhost", "127.0.0.1" and "::1". There's one more reference to "::1": "# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6" in my.ini, but note that it's commented out. There are no other references that I can find to "::" (Apologies if this comment appears twice.)

Comment: This seems to be related to ipv6, as the log message two below the one above reads "IPv6 is available."

Comment: When I run ipconfig/all "::" appears as below under "Default Gateway" in the following section:
Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 15:
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Comment: Here's where I am with my own investigation: I thought that I could maybe disable it by editing my hosts file to specifically map 127.0.0.1 to localhost. This did not help. the mysql.sock is still absent once I've rebooted and started xampp (with mysql and apache set to autostart). I'm just about despairing at this point. Tomorrow I may reinstall xampp if nobody can come up with a better idea?

Comment: This may have been a huge red-herring. I really don't know for sure how I fixed this, but for reference the additional things that I did were (in order): Reinstalled xampp, uncommented 'bind-address="127.0.0.1" ', installed mysql as a service, created a separate user in addition to the one with host set to %, this new one set to localhost. Somewhere in there (maybe in combination) was my solution, I think. Anyway I've only achieved connection (it seems) — I haven't tried to read data yet...